# fontFamily "material" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsynch with Expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-paper

#### The problem

After upgrading to the latest SDK of expo I received the following error:

> fontFamily: "material" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

I am not using "material" font anywhere and I discovered that it's an internal font / dependency of expo font.

#### My Environment

```
 System:
     OS: macOS 10.15.4
     Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
   Binaries:
     Node: 13.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
     Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
     npm: 6.14.4 - ~/.npm/bin/npm
     Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
   IDEs:
     Xcode: 11.0/11A420a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
   npmPackages:
     expo: ^36.0.2 => 36.0.2 
     react: ^16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
     react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4 
     react-navigation: ^4.3.5 => 4.3.6 
   npmGlobalPackages:
     expo-cli: 3.16.1
```

#### Place of the error where the font might be created by Expo

**Path:** /node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/build/MaterialIcons.js

```
import createIconSet from './createIconSet';
import font from './vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf';
import glyphMap from './vendor/react-native-vector-icons/glyphmaps/MaterialIcons.json';
export default createIconSet(glyphMap, 'material', font); <------ It looks like it's creating the font here.
//# sourceMappingURL=MaterialIcons.js.map
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

Upgrade to latest version of Expo SDK (36.0.2)
Add react-native-paper to project
Make a sample screen
Load custom fonts if needed

#### Steps I have undertaking already:

- Restarting computer
- Removing cache, node_modules etc and reinstall everything
- Try to link to the node modules font and load it in expo's loadAsync function like here https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/789#issuecomment-554675931
- Import font ttf file in local src and link to it with absolute path.
- [Tried suggestions in stack overflow similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030847/console-error-fontfamily-material-icons-is-not-a-system-font-and-has-not-be)
- [Tried suggestions in stack overflow similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069960/console-error-fontfamily-helvetica-neue-is-not-a-system-font-and-has-not-bee)

#### Extra information

- Active expo issue: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7552
- Active React native issue: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1768